# Sticky header covers targeted section

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, sticky

I started to make this webpage, and on the top of the page, you can see a sticky header. There is a problem with it: If I click on the labels, the header jump to the section, but because of the header you can't see some part of the targeted part.

Thank you for every help!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zkS3.jpg)

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
            
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
  header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
  header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10;
    height: 20vh;
    width:100%;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }

<header class="header" id="myHeader">
        
        <div class="logo-container" > 
        <a href="#"><img src="./img/logo.png" height="120"  alt="logo"/> </a>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#details">DETAILS</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#description">DESCRIPTION</a </li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="calendar">
            <img src="./img/calendar.png" height="40" alt="calendar" />
        </div>
```

Comment: add your html also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you give the targeted part a top padding that would allow enough space for the header? E.g.:

```
#details{
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: It helped when it is not at the starting point. Which means when the header at its original place it jumps too much, but anyway it is a good solution.